# Linear algebra: Dimension of column space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Dimension of its null space is $m < n$. What is the dimension of its column space?

Can some one please explicitly explain this? What I am majorly confused about is what this $m<n$ means?

Comment: Do you know dimension theorem?

Comment: They mean the dimension of the null space is m, and $m<n$.  Now you can use that rank(A)+nullity(A)=n.

Answer (score 0):

$m$ is the dimension of the null space or $\ker A$. $m < n$ means that it is less than the matrix size $n$.

The rank-nullity theorem says
$$
\dim \ker A + \dim \mbox{im} A = n
$$
The image of $A$ is the set of all linear combinations of the column vectors of $A$, which is the column space.
So the answer is $n - m$.